# Making live time graph without freezing gui

Tags: c#, winforms

I created matlab libary which have functions to plot graphs in live time(In (while true)loop). The problem is that when I will call this function my whole gui is frezeed. Can someone explain me how can I achive my live time graps without freezing my app? Do I have to create another thread to plot this graph? I tried to make it like this :

```
 Thread graph= new Thread(mat_lib.function_plot);

  graph.Start();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Doing this without a thread will not allow the UI to do anything until the calculation is finished. What kind of errors did you get when you tried it with the new Thread?

Comment: [How to: Make thread-safe calls to Windows Forms controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: Windows forms often hang up.  the solution is to put the code into a backgroundworker which fixes the hangup issue.

Comment: Note that threads that are not the main thread (also called GUI thread) will not work

Comment: @JakobTinhofer When I tried to make it with new thread I didn't have any errors but my GUI was still freezed.

Comment: That might be due to the mat_lib not beeing entirely threadsafe. Do you have the git repo to the lib?

Comment: @JakobTinhofer mat_lib is created by me. The script of plots is in while(true) loop. I know it might be not the best solution but I dont know better. I want to read values from my sensor in infinity loop and graph them.

Comment: I do not think that this is possible without changes to your library. Always adding new points to draw will make the library draw them constantly, freezing the whole window. Take a look at stuartd's link in order to learn how to draw to Forms thread-safely. Also, avoid a while loop and use a Queue instead.